Sampling the Dirichlet distribution from standard $[0,1]$ generator
In my understanding, an $n$-dimension Dirichlet distribution is a uniform distribution with a support on the $n-1$ dimension subplane of $\{x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n = 1, x_i \geq 0 \}$
My problem is to find an efficient implement of sampling from this Dirichlet distribution. The intuitive sampler using a standard uniform [0,1] generator is the following:

Sample $X_i \sim U[0,1]$, $i \leq n$
Compute $S = \sum X_i$
Return $(X_1 / S, X_2 / S, \dots, X_n / S)$

However, it turns out that this generator is wrong: it is not sampling from Dirichlet distribution. It turns out that we have to use a gamma distribution in step 1 instead of uniform distribution.
I need some intuitive explanation on this mistake.

Is the marginal distribution correct? From the histogram it looks fine, the marginal distribution of $X_1$ looks like a beta-distribution, but flatter than I expected(which is a beta distribution)

Why does $U[0,1]$ not work? What is the distribution my generator returned?

Intuition about why we should use gamma distribution here.

Generally, if we have i.i.d sample of $X_i \sim p(x)$, what is this algorithm returning?



Some intuition can be gained by considering the $n = 2$ choice. Your approach is equivalent to sampling from the unit square (with lower-left corner at the origin), and then projecting to the line segment between $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 0)$. Unsurprisingly, this projection does not result in a uniform distribution.

You are right. This does explain that my naive sampler is returning a wrong distrubution. Is there anyway to compute the marginal distrubution I'm sampling?

Yes, the basic approach is to consider an infinitesimal portion of the support, and identify the $n$-dimensional pyramid that projects to that portion. For $n = 2$, that leads to a PDF that has a distinct peak at the point $(1/2, 1/2)$, for example.

The $n$-dimensional Dirichlet distribution is family of distributions with support on the $n - 1$ dimensional subplane of $\{x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n = 1, x_i \geq 0 \}$ that is indexed by a non-negative parameter vector, $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ of size $n$, such that the distribution is uniform if and only if $\alpha_i = 1 \forall i$.
Wikipedia gives several algorithms to draw from a Dirichlet distribution with parameter vector $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$. If $\alpha_i = 1 \forall i$, one such algorithm that involves standard uniform generation is:

Draw $u_i \thicksim \mathcal{U}\left[0,1\right] \forall i < n$ independently from a standard uniform distribution. Note that this results in $n - 1$ realizations.
Append the fixed values $0$ and $1$ to the set of $n - 1$ realizations from step 1 to yield a set of $n + 1$ values
Sort the set from step 2 in increasing order to yield a vector $\mathbf{u}$ of size $n + 1$
Compute $x_n \equiv u_{n + 1} - u_n \forall n$

The marginal distribution of $x_1 \equiv u_2 - u_1$ is not standard uniform because it is conditional on $u_2 > u_1$ and $u_1, u_2 < u_i \forall i > 2$. But it can be shown that the marginal distribution $x_i$ is beta for all $i$ with first shape parameter equal to $\alpha_1$ and second shape parameter equal to $\sum_{j \neq i} \alpha_j$, which is much more concentrated near zero than is a standard uniform distribution. However, they are not quite independent due to the constraint that they must all sum to $1$.
It seems like you are also interested in why the sampling algorithm that you propose is not equivalent to the one above or another one that is also listed on Wikipedia that draws independently $n$ times from an exponential distribution (i.e. a special case of a Gamma distribution with parameters equal to $1$) and returns the ratios of these values to their sum.
Some intuition for using a Gamma distribution is provided by the fact that the sum of independent Gamma random variates that all have the same scale parameter ($1$ in this case) is another Gamma random variate with the same scale but whose shape parameter is the sum of the shape parameters of the original Gamma random variates. A proof is given on Wikipedia. So, dividing Gamma random variates (with a scale of $1$) by another not-independent Gamma random variate (with a scale of $1$) essentially merely cancels the common scale and puts the ratios into scale-free units. This is a bit like the fact that a correlation between two random variables is scale-independent because you divide their covariance by their respective standard deviations (that are in the same units as the original variables).
The sum of standard uniform random variates is not a uniform random variate but rather has a Irwin-Hall distribution. So, dividing standard uniform random variates by a not-independent Irwin-Hall random variate yields a $n$-dimensional random vector in the right sample space but with a different dependence structure that is not merely a canceling of scale. As far as I know, the distribution of the random vector induced by your proposed sampling procedure does not have a name but the fact that it is not uniform is implied in a comment by Brian Tung.

Rigorous simulation from a bag of independent uniform rv on $(0,1)$ of the Dirichlet distribution $D(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is possible if $a_i$ is a half integer or a  integer. Recall first that if $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ are independent gamma distributed with scale parameter 1 and shape parameters $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ then $X=\frac{(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)}{Y_1+\cdots+Y_n}\sim D(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$. Thus the real difficulty is to create $Y_i$ from the bag and this is really easy only for $a_i=1/2, 1, 3/2,\ldots.$ For $a_i=1$ you take the standard exponential random variable $Y_i=-\log U$ with $U$ in the bag. For $a_i=1/2$ you consider $Z\sim N(0,1)$ defined by $Z=-\log U_1 \times \cos 2\pi U_2$ where $U_1,U_2$ are from the bag and you take the chisquare rv $Y_i=Z^2/2$ divided by $2.$ Finally if $a_i=k$ is an integer you build $k$ independent rv exponential and you sum them to obtain $Y_i.$ If $a_i=k+\frac{1}{2} $ you add to the preceeding case the half chi square above. Exact simulation from the bag when $a_i$ has not the form $k/2$ is not known to me.
